# Axiomatized formal foundation of statistics

Tags: statistical-significance, inference, kolmogorov-axioms

I'm learning statistics in foreign language. Being aware of possibly different foundations (e.g. frequentists v.s. Bayesian), I hope to acquire *one* formally axiomatized foundation of statistics. That said, if there are multiple foundations, I'd be glad to learn about them too.

By a formally axiomatized foundation, I mean something similar to Kolmogorov's in probability. He started with measure theory, defined random variables, and from there discussed the properties of combinations of random variables.

If one has a formally defined random variable, then the discussions that follow can be formal too. Statistics, on the other hand, seems to be in search of the underlying random variable given a set of observed data. What exactly, if any, is the rigorous process that teaches us which random variable to choose based on incoming observed data?

#### Questions

1. Is there any formally axiomatized foundation of statistics?
2. In particular, I'm most interested in the process of "guessing" or "assigning likelihood" for the underlying random variables.

Comment: I perceive this as being an extremely broad question and ultimately not susceptible to any useful answer, because statistics is not a branch of mathematics.  One might just as well ask for a formal axiomatization of chemistry, for example.

Comment: If there is, then there's hope for an answer. If there's none, then it's too broad. I don't know whether there is or not.. therefore the question.

Comment: @Student: I think you might need to be more specific but the kendall, stuart and ord series might be somewhat close to what you're looking for ? I'm really not sure. Maybe try to browse one of them and see.